# Adding a log in should default to creating a Stack Exchange OpenID rather than just logging into one

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, login, stack-exchange-openid

According to the help center article [How do I add or remove login credentials from my account?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/edit-credentials) (emphasis mine):

> You can choose Google, Facebook, Yahoo!, and other popular OpenID providers; **create a new Stack Exchange OpenID by providing your email address and creating a password**; or you can manually enter another OpenID address.

The page you get to if you follow the instructions looks like:

[image: Adding a login doesn't support OpenID creation.]

As you can see, the two things the dialog prompts for are email address and password.  However, entering an email that isn't already registered gives this error:

[image: This dialog box doesn't support SE OpenID account creation.]

So either the help center article should be changed to explain how to [create an SE OpenID first](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) or the dialog box should default to allowing users to register from that page. Assuming most people expect to create a new Stack Exchange OpenID when they are adding a credential to their account, I think the later option makes more sense.  I envision the implementation being something like the [Log in/Sign up tabs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225037/why-is-the-stack-exchange-openid-option-expanded-upon-signup).

Comment: We are aware of this inconsistency. Not sure if we have the resources to bring open ID creation all the way into the pathway, but will discuss it next week.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, getting this integration in and dealing with all of the edge cases and weird re-directions is going to take more time than we have at the moment.

For now, we are just going to remove the stack exchange open ID option from adding an alternate login.

Hopefully, we can find time to come back to this later.